# laravel 5- get related products by search in Many To Many

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

```
Table 1: products: id,title
Table 2: features: id,name,values
Table 3:feature_product:id,product_id,values
```

I want get all related products when I search in `values` in `feature_product` table.

I do these:

in product model:

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class)->withPivot('values');
}

public function feature()
{
    // ???
}
```

and query for search:

```
 $q = 'yellow';
 $query->where(function($query) use ($q)
 {
    $query->WhereHas('feature' , function ($query) use 
    ($q){$query->where('values' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $q . '%' );});
 }
```

how can I search in related features of products? (and get those products)

I think I must do something in this function in product model:

```
public function feature()
{
        // ???
}
```

Comment: you have to define `belongsToMany()` relation in both of the models. both would same, just change the model names in it.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: @NaveedAli Yes, with this: `$query->WhereHas('features' , function ($query) use 
    ($q){$query->where('feature_product.values' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $q . '%' );});`  . your comment help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in product model:

```
public function features()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class)->withPivot('values');
}

public function feature()
{
   // ??
}
```

in Feature Model:

```
public function products(){
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('values');
}
```

and query search

```
$query->WhereHas('features' , function ($query) use ($q) {
$query->where('feature_product.values' , 'LIKE' , '%' . $q . '%' );
});
```